# Asp.net MVC Model for view and Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to find a good way to handle the Models of our Asp.net MVC websites when having common properties for all the pages. These properties are to be displayed in the Layout (Master Page). I'm using a "BaseModel" class that holds those properties and my Layout use this BaseModel as its model.

Every other model inherits from that BaseModel and each has specific properties relative to the view it represents. As you might have guessed, my Models are actually View Models even if that's not quite relevant here.

I have tried different ways to initialize the BaseModel values

1. By "hand" in every view
2. Having a base controller that has an Initialize virtual method to do it (so specific controller can implement specific common behavior for exemple)
3. Having a base controlelr that override OnActionExecuting to call the Initialize method
4. Using a helper class to do it outside of the controller
5. Using a Model Factory

But none of those really appeal to me:

1. Seems obvious to me, but DRY is one reason enough to justify that (actually I never tried that solution at all, I'm just putting it to be able to loop on that point in the last point).
2. I don't like that one because it means that whenever a new Controller is added, you need to know that it has to inherit from the BaseController and that you need to call the Initialize method, not to mention that if your controller has overriden the base one, to call the base anyway to maintain the values.
3. see next point
4. and 3. are a variation on the same topic but that doesn't really help with the issues of the second solution.
5. My favorite so far, but now I have to pass a few more variables to set those values. I like it for the inversion of dependence. But then if I want to provide values from the session, I need to pass them explicitly for exemple, then I'm back to square one as I have to provide them by hand (being references or through an interface of any kind)

Of course, (almost) all of those solutions work, but I'm looking for a better way to do it.

While typing this question, I found maybe a new path, the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) that might also do, but implementations can become quickly a burden too, as we can have dozens of views and controllers.

I'll gladly take any serious recommandation/hint/advice/patterns/suggestion !

**Update**

Thanks to @EBarr I came up with another solution, using an ActionFilterAttribute (not production code, did it in 5 minutes):

```
public class ModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public Type ModelType { get; private set; }

    public ModelAttribute(string typeName) : this(Type.GetType(typeName)) { }

    public ModelAttribute(Type modelType)
    {
        if(modelType == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("modelType"); }

        ModelType = modelType;
        if (!typeof(BaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(ModelType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("model type should inherit BaseModel");
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var model = ModelFactory.GetModel(ModelType);

        var foo = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["foo"] as Foo;

        model.Foo = foo;
        model.Bar = somevalue;

        filterContext.Controller.TempData["model"] = model;
    } 
}
```

Calling it is then really simple:

```
[Model(typeof(HomeModel))]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var homeModel = TempData["model"] as HomeModel;

    // Add View Specific stuff

    return View(homeModel);
}
```

And it gives me the best of every world. The only drawback is to find a proper way to passe the model back to the action.

Here it's done using the TempData object, but I also consider updating the model that one can find in the ActionParameters.

I'm still taking  any serious recommandation/hint/advice/patterns/suggestion for that, or the previous points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea that gave me @EBarr to use an action filter was actually working but felt wrong in the end, because there was no clean way to retrieve the model without passing through a viewbag, or the httpcontext items, or something alike. Also, it made mandatory to decorate every action with its model. It also made the postback more difficult to handle. I still believe that this solution has merits and might be useful in some specific scenarios.

So I was back to square one and started looking more into that topic. I came to the following. First the problem has two aspects

1. Initializing the data for the views
2. Rendering the data

While looking for more idea, I realized that I was not looking at the problem from the right perspective. I was looking at it from a "Controller" POV, whereas the final client for the model is the view. I was also reminded that the Layout/Master page is not a view and should not have a model associated with it. That insight put me on what feels the right path for me. Because it meant that every "dynamic" part of the Layout should be handled outside of it. Of course, sections seems the perfect fit for that, because of their flexibility.

On the test solution I made, I had (only) 4 different sections, some mandatory, some not. The problem with sections, is that you need to add them on every page, which can quickly be a pain to update/modify. To solve that, I tried this:

```
public interface IViewModel
{
    KeyValuePair<string, PartialViewData>[] Sections { get; }
}

public class PartialViewData
{
    public string PartialViewName { get; set; }
    public object PartialViewModel { get; set; }
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
}
```

For exemple, my model for the view is this:

```
public class HomeViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public Article[] Articles { get; set; }             // Article is just a dummy class 
    public string QuickContactMessage { get; set; }     // just here to try things

    public HomeViewModel() { Articles = new Article[0]; }

    private Dictionary<string, PartialViewData> _Sections = new Dictionary<string, PartialViewData>();
    public KeyValuePair<string, PartialViewData>[] Sections
    {
        get { return _Sections.ToArray(); }
        set { _Sections = value.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value); }
    }
}
```

This get initialized in the action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var hvm = ModelFactory.Get<HomeViewModel>(); // Does not much, basicaly a new HomeViewModel();

    hvm.Sections = LayoutHelper.GetCommonSections().ToArray(); // more on this just after
    hvm.Articles = ArticlesProvider.GetArticles(); // ArticlesProvider could support DI

    return View(hvm);
}
```

LayoutHelper is a property on the controller (which could be DI'ed if needed):

```
public class DefaultLayoutHelper
{
    private Controller Controller;
    public DefaultLayoutHelper(Controller controller) { Controller = controller; }

    public Dictionary<string, PartialViewData> GetCommonSections(QuickContactModel quickContactModel = null)
    {
        var sections = new Dictionary<string, PartialViewData>();
        // those calls were made in methods in the solution, I removed it to reduce the length of the answer
        sections.Add("header",
                     Controller.UserLoggedIn() // simple extension that check if there is a user logged in
                     ? new PartialViewData { PartialViewName = "HeaderLoggedIn", PartialViewModel = new HeaderLoggedInViewModel { Username = "Bishop" } } 
                     : new PartialViewData { PartialViewName = "HeaderNotLoggedIn", PartialViewModel = new HeaderLoggedOutViewModel() });
        sections.Add("quotes", new PartialViewData { PartialViewName = "Quotes" });
        sections.Add("quickcontact", new PartialViewData { PartialViewName = "QuickContactForm", PartialViewModel = model ?? new QuickContactModel() });
        return sections;
    }
}
```

And in the views (.cshtml):

```
@section       quotes { @{ Html.RenderPartial(Model.Sections.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "quotes").Value); } }
@section        login { @{ Html.RenderPartial(Model.Sections.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "header").Value); } }
@section       footer { @{ Html.RenderPartial(Model.Sections.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "footer").Value); } }
```

The actual solution has more code, I tried to simplify to just get the idea here. It's still a bit raw and need polishing/error handling, but with that I can define in my action, what the sections will be, what model they will use and so on. It can be easily tested and setting up DI should not be an issue.

I still have to duplicate the @section lines in every view, which seems a bit painful (especialy because we can't put the sections in a partial view).

I'm looking into the [templated razor delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx) to see if that could not replace the sections.

Answer (score 2):

I went through almost exactly the same process as I dove into MVC.  And you're right, none of the solutions feel that great.

In the end I used a series of base models. For various reasons I had a few different types of base models, but the logic should apply to a single base type.  The majority of my view models then inherited from one of the bases.  Then, depending on need/timing i fill the base portion of the model in `ActionExecuting` or `OnActionExecuted`.

A snippet of my code that should make the process clear:

```
if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("model")) {
   var tempModel = (System.Object)filterContext.ActionParameters["model"];

   if (typeof(BaseModel_SuperLight).IsAssignableFrom(tempModel.GetType())) {
       //do stuff required by light weight model
   }

   if (typeof(BaseModel_RegularWeight).IsAssignableFrom(tempModel.GetType())) {
      //do more costly stuff for regular weight model here
   }
}
```

In the end my pattern didn't feel too satisfying.  It was, however, practical, flexible and easy to implement varying levels of inheritance.  I was also able to inject pre or post controller execution, which mattered a lot in my case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. While it doesn't exactly match what I'm looking for (your solution is a different implementation of 3.), it actually gave me an idea. I just tried using a custom ActionFilterAttribute that seems to do the trick. I still need to figure a "clean" way to give the model back to the action (right now I'm using the TempData). I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, it is a version of #3.  I thought about attributes, but that required decorating each controller/action (depending on need).  Keeping it in the `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` kept my code in a single base controller.  In practice for any larger MVC project you're going to have a base controller, so I didn't mind so much.  It also allowed me to run the logic based on model type, instead of tying the logic to which action was executing.

Comment: RE: Grabbing model: In your action filter attribute you're going to end up implementing the same events (exeucting and executed), but you can grab the model out of the filterContext, no need to hand it back, just find it and fill what you need.